# Custom fields Wordpress and foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have problem with custom fields in wordpress.

I have subpage:

- Home PL
- Home DE
- Home EN

I have added custom fields to each subpage which in each language are the same.

e.g

```
<?php the_field('text1'); ?>
<?php the_field('text2'); ?>
<?php the_field('text3'); ?>
```

Everything works fine until I add a loop that displays an offer from that subcategory.

e.g

```
    $args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 
'post_parent' => 44, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order'   => 'ASC', );
    $parents = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($parents as $post) :  
      setup_postdata($post);
    endforeach;
```

Below the loop when you want to add custom fields it does not work. How to solve this?

Comment: When I add <?php the_field('text', ID); This starts to work, but it does not work in other languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do **the_field()** inside the loop.

Comment: This is a bad solution. And do not want to have custom fields in the loop, I want to custom fields below loop.

Comment: But that is how WordPress loop works. The loop functions, the_title, the_content, the_field... etc only make sense inside of 'The WordPress Loop' that has setup the post data (a global $post). You can check out get_metadata() https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata if you don't want to use the 'loop' functions.